# Unable to edit a Choice field with Checkboxes and fill-in choices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, choice-field

I'm a fairly novice SP user, however I've run into an issue. I've created a list, and one of the columns is a 'Choice' with checkboxes so users can select multiple items. When I set the 'Allow fill-in choices' to No, everything works well. However, when I set it to Yes, all of a sudden that field becomes uneditable. When I go to create a new item, it works fine. However, if I try to edit the list directly, there's no drop down and no way to edit that field.

[image: What it looks like with 'Allow fill in' set to No]
[image: When it's set to Yes[![The 'New Item' works well]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUyD9.png)

'New Item' works fine'

[image: Not working]

This is what it looks like when I'm trying to edit this field on the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's **by design**, you can't use `Allow 'Fill-in' choices` with  `Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)` in `Quick Edit`.

**The available options to use `Quick Edit` for the choice field:**

- Use `Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)` without  `Allow 'Fill-in' choices`, or

[image]

- Use `Drop-Down Menu` or `Radio Buttons` with  `Allow 'Fill-in' choices`.

[image]